# Extract row from Deedle and convert to Matrix

Tags: f#, deedle, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I am trying to extract a row from a Deedle `Frame` and convert it to a flat (1x4) `DenseMatrix`.
All missing values have been dropped and the values in the `Frame` are numerical.

My code:

```
let matrix =
    let curr = seq { yield frame.GetRowAt(10).As<float>() |> Series.values }
    DenseMatrix.ofSeq curr
```

produces the error:

> error FS0192: internal error: convMethodRef: could not bind to method

It is interesting to note that also:

```
let try2 =
    let mySeq = seq { yield seq { 1.0 .. 10.0} }
    DenseMatrix.ofSeq mySeq
```

produces the same error.

I have updated to 11.0.061030.00 (update 4) with .Net 4.5.50709, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: This looks like an F# compiler bug - what version of F# or Visual Studio are  you using?

Comment: @Tomas: Thanks for your help. I am on VS12 v11.0.60610.01 Update 3; MS .Net 4.5.50709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referencing Math.NET Numerics v2 or v3?

In v3 there is no `DenseMatrix.ofSeq` but instead `DenseMatrix.ofColumnSeq` and `DenseMatrix.ofRowSeq`.